# TCL coming up with a general code

Tags: tcl

I am using tcl. Below is the code I have so far; is there a better way to do this?

```
if {$parname == "Wbay1" || $parname == "Wbay2" } {
    set  count  [string index $parname end]
    set Wbay$count  [lindex $elem 1]
    puts "set Wbay$count  [lindex $elem 1]"
}
```

Be more general like this

```
if {$parname == "Wbay*" } {
    set  count  [string index $parname end]
    set Wbay$count  [lindex $elem 1]
    puts "set Wbay$count  [lindex $elem 1]"

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the names are `Wbay1`, ..., `Wbay9`, you can use

```
if {[string match {Wbay[1-9]} $parname]} {
    set $parname [lindex $elem 1]
}
```

If the number part can be greater than 9, you should use

```
if {[regexp {Wbay\d+} $parname]} {
    set $parname [lindex $elem 1]
}
```

A `regexp` (regular expression) match is more powerful than a string match. In this case, `\d+` means "one or more digits".

If you want to record the highest number you've seen so far, use

```
set maxN 0
...
if {[regexp {Wbay(\d+)} $parname -> n]} {
    set maxN [expr {max($n, $maxN)}]
    set $parname [lindex $elem 1]
}
```

The parenthesis means that you want to capture the matched string within, i.e. the number. The `->` symbol is a variable name: it's a convention that is often used to store the full match (e.g. "Wbay7") when we don't care about it. The variable `n` is set to the number that was captured. If `regexp` doesn't return 1, the value in `n` can't be trusted: the variable will keep whatever value it had before. The variable `maxN` is set to whichever of `$n` and `$maxN` is greatest.

But you might also find an array variable useful. With an array, you name the individual members `Wbay(1)`, `Wbay(2)`, `Wbay(99)`, etc (they don't have to be consecutive or in order). If you want to know how many members you have, `array size Wbay` will tell you.

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[max (function)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Comment: Great ! One more question
If i wanna do it for a more general case to cover all the cases Wbay1, Wbay2,Wbay3...Wbayn 
Then instead of Wbay[12] , what should I put?

I want the code intelligently to recognize how many Waby’s exist and catch them? 

Thanks very much !